# How to group an already grouped data-set in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: Problem dataset]

[image: Expected output]

**I want to first group data as per "Roll" and then further group it as per "Name" with different "Marks"**.
I have grouped data using *Group by and having* but I am not sure how to further group it.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, don't use pictures to provide code . Use plain text formatting as code

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  Is one of the images supposed to be input data?  Or are you trying to generate both result sets with one query?  What happened to Sham?

Answer (score 0):

Group by two columns :

```
SELECT Roll,Name FROM table GROUP BY Roll,Name;
```

If you want to see marks also you have aggegrate(sum) it like :

```
SELECT Roll,Name,sum(Marks)as 'Total Marks' FROM table GROUP BY Roll,Name;
```

If you want to see marks also you have aggegrate(average) it like :

```
SELECT Roll,Name,avg(Marks)as 'Average Marks' FROM table GROUP BY Roll,Name;
```

[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVYmz.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `roll`/`name` pairs that have multiple distinct values.  You can do this using window functions:

```
select distinct roll, name, marks
from (select t.*, count(distinct marks) over (partition by roll, name) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```